# (re-) activating slices of 3d-volume WEBGL

Tags: webgl, xtk

when i try to switch between the directions (x,y,z), i get an uncommon result. when i reactivate the layer(s) of a direction which has been set to **visible = false** before (1), it looks like this if i change the visiblity to **true** (2). this example relies on [xtk lesson #10](http://lessons.goxtk.com/10/) [sorry for the low jpg-quality]

thanks in advance

(1)

[image: 1]

(2)

[image: 2]

**EDIT:** i try to show/activate only one direction and go through the layers by pressing +/-.

unfortunately "avf.nrrd" is missing at the moment.

i know how to do this with all 3 layers activated. it works perfectly and i can go through the slices and change the axis on keydown. but now i would like to do the same but this time i want to deactivate the 2 axis which are *not* selected

**EDIT2:** alright i got it all working. the only problem was to position the line *modified()* to the right line.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0rter/HG955/)

Comment: I think you are missing a volume.modified() call to update the slicing. Could you prevent a JSFiddle - then I can take a look much easier.

Comment: nice that you got it working. also the url to the datasets has changed http://x.babymri.org/?avf.nrrd